# Weird Issue with pdflatex.exe MikTex and Texmaker

Tags: miktex, installing, texmaker

When I try to run Quick Build from TexMaker. I get the error:

```
Could not start the command.
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

I checked to make sure that `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64` is on mypath, which it is, and that `pdflatex.exe` is in that folder.

I opened up a command prompt and ran `pdflatex` and got the following output:

```
Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:/Users/.../AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/initexmf.log

You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.

Sorry, but pdflatex did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:/Users/.../AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/pdflatex.log

You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.
```

I went to the log file in that error message and this is what is inside:

```
2018-01-18 13:12:46,690-0500 INFO  pdflatex - starting with command line: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode test2.tex
2018-01-18 13:12:46,696-0500 INFO  pdflatex - running 'initexmf' to refresh the file name database
2018-01-18 13:12:46,890-0500 FATAL pdflatex - The executed process did not succeed.
2018-01-18 13:12:46,890-0500 FATAL pdflatex - Info: fileName="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\initexmf.exe", exitCode="1"
2018-01-18 13:12:46,890-0500 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Process\Process.cpp
2018-01-18 13:12:46,890-0500 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 156
2018-01-18 13:12:46,890-0500 INFO  pdflatex - finishing with exit code 1
2018-01-18 13:12:53,694-0500 INFO  pdflatex - starting with command line: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode test2.tex
2018-01-18 13:12:53,701-0500 INFO  pdflatex - running 'initexmf' to refresh the file name database
2018-01-18 13:12:53,911-0500 FATAL pdflatex - The executed process did not succeed.
2018-01-18 13:12:53,911-0500 FATAL pdflatex - Info: fileName="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\initexmf.exe", exitCode="1"
2018-01-18 13:12:53,911-0500 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Process\Process.cpp
2018-01-18 13:12:53,911-0500 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 156
2018-01-18 13:12:53,911-0500 INFO  pdflatex - finishing with exit code 1
2018-01-18 13:16:04,914-0500 INFO  pdflatex - starting with command line: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode test2.tex
2018-01-18 13:16:04,920-0500 INFO  pdflatex - running 'initexmf' to refresh the file name database
2018-01-18 13:16:05,106-0500 FATAL pdflatex - The executed process did not succeed.
2018-01-18 13:16:05,106-0500 FATAL pdflatex - Info: fileName="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\initexmf.exe", exitCode="1"
2018-01-18 13:16:05,106-0500 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Process\Process.cpp
2018-01-18 13:16:05,106-0500 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 156
2018-01-18 13:16:05,106-0500 INFO  pdflatex - finishing with exit code 1
2018-01-18 13:16:17,131-0500 INFO  pdflatex - starting with command line: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode test2.tex
2018-01-18 13:16:17,138-0500 INFO  pdflatex - running 'initexmf' to refresh the file name database
2018-01-18 13:16:17,325-0500 FATAL pdflatex - The executed process did not succeed.
2018-01-18 13:16:17,325-0500 FATAL pdflatex - Info: fileName="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\initexmf.exe", exitCode="1"
2018-01-18 13:16:17,325-0500 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Process\Process.cpp
2018-01-18 13:16:17,325-0500 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 156
2018-01-18 13:16:17,325-0500 INFO  pdflatex - finishing with exit code 1
2018-01-18 13:17:05,511-0500 INFO  pdflatex - starting with command line: pdflatex
```

Does anyone know what this means? I am just trying to use TexMaker with MikTex installed on my machine.

Comment: What happens if you try just launching `pdflatex`?

Comment: If you have time, then I would deinstall and reinstall MiKTeX without digging deeper.

Comment: For some reason when I used the editor that came with MikTex it worked and then when I switched over to Texmate everything was working? Is there some kind of final or first time configuration that occurs when you use the editor that comes with MikTex?

Comment: What version of TeXmaker are you using? I started having the same issue after the turn of the year.

Comment: (A maybe) Stupid suggestion: When my miktex is having problems (which happens around every third to fourth week), I do miktex update (admin) twice, then miktex settings (admin) and click update FNDB and formats. It's not like I thoroughly understand what both of these do, but it's like miktex had been working tirelessly for two weeks, so I send it to bed, clean its shovel and sharpen its scythe (I really don't want to know what it does with its tools, but it gets the work done), then it gets back to work with renewed impetus :DD personifications help me to make sense of the world around me.